CameraPreview zoomed in 2x as Surface View
How can I implement a Surface View from a camera preview that is zoomed in by 2?
I'm writing an android app that uses the camera preview as the surface view with a GUI displayed over that.
Currently everything works, but, I can't seem to get the surface view to display as zoomed in by 2x.
I don't need to zoom in/out. I just need the preview to display zoomed in by 2x.
This is my first attempt at writing an app. Any help at all would be welcome and appreciated.
Thank you.
I've tried adding code to implement a pinch to zoom function, but, that didn't work. Can't seem to get it to always show me a preview that is 2x.

Does this answer your question? How can I implement a 2x camera view as surface view?
